Help me SMD diode identifying
I need to identify a diode. Can you please help me?

Package : 1,60x1,30x0,80 (probably SOD-323). I'ts a diode (TVS).


Without readable markings, it's impossible to identify. Please take a better picture.

You can see the new image I've added, but I don't have a better view of the marking than this one

It is a 1SS355 diode from Rohm.
(Marking A with traceability dots above)

Picture from akidukidenshi

